# Find the equation that determines the x coordinates (x∗) of the fixed points of the model represented by these two ODEs?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, nonlinear-dynamics

I am working on a nonlinear dynamics problem set and I have a question about deriving the equation that determines the x coordinates (x∗) of the fixed points of the model represented by these two ODEs.

$\dot{x} = y - x^3 + 3x^2 + I$

$\dot{y} = 1 - 5x^2 - y$

The fixed points are the intersections of the two ODEs, thus I think that you can obtain the nullclines and then set the equations for the nullclines equal to each other?

$\dot{x} -nullcline:  y = x^3 - 3x^2 + I$

$\dot{y} -nullcline:  y = 1 - 5x^2$

Making the equation to determine the values of x the simplified version of:

$x^3 - 3x^2 + I = 1 - 5x^2$

Is that the proper way to find the equation that determines the x coordinates (x∗) of the fixed points of the model represented by these two ODEs? I apologize if my question is silly!

Thanks so much.

Comment: What is $I$ in the $\dot{x}$ equation?

Comment: Your approach is, I think, correct on concept. You have a sign error in the $\dot{x}$ equation. You should have $y=x^3+3x^2-I,$ whatever $I$ is.

Comment: I is a constant, can assume it is just zero!

Comment: Well, you have a cubic polynomial to solve, which is usually fairly straight-forward. I find computers helpful.